# Format a caption created with Selection. InsertCaption (Word VBA)

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I'd like to format a caption created with the Selection.InsertCaption method in a Word document with VBA (centering the text inside the caption, change font size and colour).

My code so far:

```
For i = 1 To (mInlinShapes.Count) 'looping through my document inlineshapes
    If (mInlinShapes(i).Type = wdInlineShapePicture) Then
            Set Shp = mInlinShapes(i).ConvertToShape
            Shp.Select
            With Selection
                .InsertCaption Label:=wdCaptionFigure, _
                              Title:=" a custom title", _
                              Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, _
                              ExcludeLabel:=0

            End With
            Shp.ConvertToInlineShape
    End If
Next i
```

I'd rather avoid re-looping through all my captions to apply formatting, if possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the Job for You:

```
For i = 1 To (mInlinShapes.Count) 'looping through my document inlineshapes
    If (mInlinShapes(i).Type = wdInlineShapePicture) Then
            Set Shp = mInlinShapes(i).ConvertToShape
            Shp.Select
            With Selection
                .InsertCaption Label:=wdCaptionFigure, _
                              Title:=" a custom title", _
                              Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow, _
                              ExcludeLabel:=0

            End With

            With ActiveDocument.Styles("Caption").Font

                .Name = "Times New Roman"
                .Size = 18
                .ColorIndex = wdBrightGreen

            End With

            Shp.ConvertToInlineShape
    End If
Next i
```

For more properties Go here: [Link](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-ways-change-caption-style-word-document/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, do you know if I could avoid shp.select to insert my caption? I tried using shp.range but no success (layout gets messed up).